# journalctl to search metadata with regex

Tags: regex, linux

Is it possible to search in journalctl via metadata with patterns. What I am doing right now is to search like `journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=cranky.hello --lines=100 -f`. But what I want to achieve is to search everything after that '.'. Some search pattern like `journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=cranky.* --lines=100 -f`. Which will also search **CONTAINER_NAME** metadata like:

- cranky.world
- cranky.alive

Below are example of output when journalctl is executed:

**journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=cranky.hello --lines=100 -f**

`Oct 17 14:33:35 lottery-staging docker[55587]:   chdir: /usr/src/app
Oct 17 14:33:35 lottery-staging docker[55587]:   daemon: False
Oct 17 14:33:35 lottery-staging docker[55587]:   raw_env: []
Oct 17 14:33:35 lottery-staging docker[55587]:   pidfile: None
Oct 17 14:33:35 lottery-staging docker[55587]:   worker_tmp_dir: None`

**journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=cranky.hello --lines=100 -f -o json**

`{ "__CURSOR" : "s=d98b3d664a71409d9a4d6145b0f8ad93;i=731e;b=2f9d75ec91044d52b8c5e5091370bcf7;m=285b067a063;t=55bbf0361352a;x=64b377c33c8fba96", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1508250837136682", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "2773213487203", "_BOOT_ID" : "2f9d75ec91044d52b8c5e5091370bcf7", "CONTAINER_TAG" : "", "_TRANSPORT" : "journal", "_PID" : "55587", "_UID" : "0", "_GID" : "0", "_COMM" : "docker", "_EXE" : "/usr/bin/docker", "_CMDLINE" : "/usr/bin/docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --userland-proxy=false --tlscert /etc/dockercloud/agent/cert.pem --tlskey /etc/dockercloud/agent/key.pem --tlscacert /etc/dockercloud/agent/ca.pem --tlsverify --log-driver journald", "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/", "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : [ 117, 110, 99, 111, 110, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 10 ], "_MACHINE_ID" : "0a80624bd4c45a792b0a857c59a858d6", "_HOSTNAME" : "lottery-staging", "PRIORITY" : "6", "MESSAGE" : "Running migrations:", "CONTAINER_ID_FULL" : "c8f60546e9d50f034f364259c409760b3390d979d57a773eccd8d852e1c3553f", "CONTAINER_NAME" : "ghost-1.lottery-staging-stack.c6118be4", "CONTAINER_ID" : "c8f60546e9d5", "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1508250837135650" }
{ "__CURSOR" : "s=d98b3d664a71409d9a4d6145b0f8ad93;i=731f;b=2f9d75ec91044d52b8c5e5091370bcf7;m=285b067a2a2;t=55bbf0361376a;x=6c87fea4ea155d00", "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1508250837137258", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "2773213487778", "_BOOT_ID" : "2f9d75ec91044d52b8c5e5091370bcf7", "CONTAINER_TAG" : "", "_TRANSPORT" : "journal", "_PID" : "55587", "_UID" : "0", "_GID" : "0", "_COMM" : "docker", "_EXE" : "/usr/bin/docker", "_CMDLINE" : "/usr/bin/docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 --userland-proxy=false --tlscert /etc/dockercloud/agent/cert.pem --tlskey /etc/dockercloud/agent/key.pem --tlscacert /etc/dockercloud/agent/ca.pem --tlsverify --log-driver journald", "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/", "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : [ 117, 110, 99, 111, 110, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 10 ], "_MACHINE_ID" : "0a80624bd4c45a792b0a857c59a858d6", "_HOSTNAME" : "lottery-staging", "PRIORITY" : "6", "MESSAGE" : "  No migrations to apply.", "CONTAINER_ID_FULL" : "c8f60546e9d50f034f364259c409760b3390d979d57a773eccd8d852e1c3553f", "CONTAINER_NAME" : "ghost-1.lottery-staging-stack.c6118be4", "CONTAINER_ID" : "c8f60546e9d5", "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1508250837135667" }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`journalctl` does not accept patterns for anything other than unit names (in the `-u` argument).  Depending on your needs, you could perform some filtering using JSON output and `grep`, as in:

```
journalctl -u docker -o json -n1000 | grep 'CONTAINER_NAME.*cranky\.'
```

Comment: I updated my answer showing sample logs, your command did not work by the way

Comment: Your sample output does not include anything from containers named `cranky` anything.  I see `"CONTAINER_NAME" : "ghost-1.lottery-staging-stack.c6118be4"`, so following the example here you could run `... | grep 'CONTAINER_NAME.*ghost'` if you wanted to find that line.

Comment: still the same though.. the `-u docker` itself does not return any log